# How to sort foreach items from SQL by date (Today, Yesterday, 29 Aug, 28, etc.) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, mariadb

Sorry, I couldn't explain it more in the title but here's the deal.

I have a SQL table with items which have a classic date column where I ordered them by date in the loop. Now I want to add an `echo` into an existing loop to display a row in the looped table which will show Items added today, Items added yesterday and so forth.

This is how I'd like it to look when looped. (The closest I got was it looped by every second and added echoed part per every item which was a total mess)

**PS:** Reading on google maybe it should be included as `usort` with `if` inside existing `foreach`?

```
----------------------------
Table
----------------------------
echoed `<tr><td>Added: today<td></tr>`
---------------------------
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
---------------------------
echoed `<tr><td>Added: yesterday<td></tr>`
---------------------------
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
---------------------------
echoed `<tr><td>Added: 29 Aug<td></tr>`
---------------------------
Item 9
Item 10
Item 11
etc
```

**Edit:** Date format doesn't have to be 29 Aug. It's just for the reference I'll tweak it myself. I just need a help with the logic of how to implement this.

Comment: Please, show your query. It's possible to sort on MySQL level, have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't know it could be done by mysql. `SELECT * FROM `todo_list` ORDER BY `added` DESC $limit` This is how I did and then just took the items into the foreach to loop as a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should sort them first in the database!

then when looping through the items you essentially remember which section you last displayed, and before outputting the first row of a new section, you output the section title instead:

```
$current = null;

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $display = date_create($row['timestamp'])->format('Ymd');  // or whatever!
    // it must consistently return something that makes the following consistent:
    if($display != $current) {
        // add separator that contains "today" or "yesterday" or the date 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$display.'</td></tr>';
        $current = $display;
    }

    // display the actual row here
}
```

the problem gets harder, if you want to also show separator rows for dates that don't exist in database. then, you would have to create a date object first, and subtract one day at a time until the date matches the rows date, outputting separators accordingly.

**update**: special displays (please note, that `$today` and `$yesterday` must be simple types like string or int or something for this to work):

```
// before the loop!
$today = date_create()->format('Ymd');
$yesterday = date_create("-1 day")->format('Ymd');
$replacements = [
    $today => 'today', // or whatever
    $yesterday => 'yesterday', // or whatever
];
```

in the loop when echoing the `$display`:

```
echo '<tr><td>'.($replacements[$display] ?? $display).'</td></tr>';
```

this will look, if the formatted date should be replaced.

Comment: Wow! It actually works the way I wanted. Need more testing to check if everything works as it should. Thank you! By the way how should I format first and second day as today and yesterday, other forms are easy.

Comment: That solved all the issues! Thank you so much. Now I learned that it's not that hard to format dates

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that you have already got the data sorted on the basis of days i.e. the field "added".

What you can do next is to loop through the retrieved result set. This is how you can proceed.

```
$dtPrevDate = null;
```

The above variable is going to be useful for the purpose of comparison of the dates i.e. "added".

Now loop through the retrieved data:

```
foreach($data as $datum){
 if($dtPrevDate == $datum['added']){
  // Keep printing item
 }
 else{
  echo "Item added on: $datum['added']";
 }
 $dtPrevDate = $datum['added'];
}
```

The essence of the above code is dependent on the sorting that you have already managed to do using MySQL.